# EF Core version 8.0.0-rc Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'Domains.Stock.Infra.Data.Context.StockInfraContext'

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to execute a migration with EF Core, and I'm getting this
error:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type
> 'Domains.Stock.Infra.Data.Context.StockInfraContext'. The exception
> 'Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Domains.Stock.Infra.Data.Context.StockInfraContext]'

My context

```cs
public class StockInfraContext : DbContext
{
    public required DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public required DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public required DbSet<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
    public required DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public required DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public required DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    public StockInfraContext(DbContextOptions<StockInfraContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Stock");

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CategoryConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TradeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new SupplierConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AddressConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactConfiguration());
    }
}
```

my IoC

```cs
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    private static IServiceCollection InternalAddStockIoc(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<StockInfraContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("PsqlConnection"),
            optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(StockInfraContext).Assembly.FullName)
                .MigrationsHistoryTable(HistoryRepository.DefaultTableName, "Stocks")));

        services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ITradeRepository, TradeRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ISupplierRepository, SupplierRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IAddressRepository, AddressRepository>();

        return services;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection ExposeStockIoC(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return InternalAddStockIoc(services, configuration);
    }
}
```

and my App

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

builder.Services
    .ExposeStockIoC(builder.Configuration);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add your DbContext to the services collection after the builder has already built. Swap the order in your Program.cs accordingly:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .ExposeStockIoC(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();
//...
```

Additionally, you need a way for the Migrations tool to instantiate `StockInfraContext` at design-time. The way you have it written now, it doesn't know how to instantiate it which is leading to your exception. You can read more about this [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

In short you have a couple of options:

1. If your DbContext instance will have the same options for migrations as it will for run-time, you can simply add to the bottom of your Program.cs the following (assuming you're using top-level statements):

```cs
public partial class Program
{
    // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Program>());
}
```

2. If you need to modify how the DbContext is instantiated at design-time versus run-time, create a class that implements `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<StockInfraContext>`:

```cs
public class StockInfraContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<StockInfraContext>
{
    public StockInfraContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        // sample configuration / option building, your use-case will vary
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StockInfraContext>();
        var env = args.FirstOrDefault();

        var jsonFile = "";

        if (env == "Production")
        {
            jsonFile = "appsettings.json";
        }
        else if (env == "Staging")
        {
            jsonFile = "appsettings.Staging.json";
        }
        else if (env is "Development")
        {
            jsonFile = "appsettings.Development.json";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("No appsettings.json for environment named " + env);
        }

        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(jsonFile);

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StockInfraContext>();
        var config = configBuilder.Build();

        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(config.GetConnectionString("PsqlConnection"));
        // more options here...

        return new StockInfraContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but i got the same error again

Comment: @RodrigoBatista I noticed another issue in your code, I edited the beginning of my answer to include how to fix that. Let me know if you continue having issues (and include if it's the same exception or a different one, like you did in your last comment)